# Failed to create service Invalid wsdl but it works in the test

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, java-ee-8, ws

Environment:

- IntelliJ in debug
- JBoss 7.2
- Java 11
- jaxws 2.3.0

I have created a client in a JUnit test and work well.
The problem comes when I try to execute the method normally.
I get the error 'Failed to create service' Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /soapenv:Reason): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'

I use the "base" service URL.

I've tried to use "base" service URL + ?wsdl in normal method and works well. Why is that?

Any idea what could it be?

**Error**

```
09:37:26,838 ERROR [es.caib.accfor.business.QueryService] (default task-4) Renova silcoiEmpleoClient: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
...
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.impl//org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.impl//org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.impl//org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
    ... 149 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /soapenv:Reason): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'.
    ...
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependencies>
    <!-- Especificacions i llibreries proporcionades per JBoss -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-8.0</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Anotacions de documentació de openapi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>microprofile-openapi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Altres mòduls del projecte -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.caib.accfor</groupId>
        <artifactId>accfor-commons</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.caib.accfor</groupId>
        <artifactId>accfor-persistence</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Altres llibreries necessàries per aquest mòdul -->
    <!-- Només necessària per la generació de codi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.11</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!--Dependencies per ws silcoi-->
    <!-- JAXWS for Java 11 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependències de test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <!-- Per tests amb Arquillian -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
        <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <!-- Per fer tests d'integració amb base de dades en memòria -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /soapenv:Reason): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element **'{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'**.

It seems that it doesn't recognize the root element: < wsdl:definitions >.
check that your wsdl is correct.